# Products don't appear in the products view page as they should

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-view, phtml

The problem i am dealing with is the following, i have added 5 products in my site which are displayed in a slider in the homepage, but when i click on a certain product i can see the page menu, both header and the footer but not the product itself it's like the product view page is missing. I changed the design of  certain product into 2 columns with left side bar, then i refreshed my homepage page and clicked on a product again, this time it appeared. I believe there is a problem with`product-view.phtml`.
What can i do to make the products appear as they should?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't leave an comment yet I will post this as an answer to help you find the problem.

You said that when you changed the lay-out the product was displayed correct, this indicates that the problem is with the `lay-out` files instead of view.phtml. You could try and have a look in the corresponding lay-out file of your product to see if you see something strange there.

Since there was a blank page it is likely there was an exception, have you checked the `exception.log` and `system.log` in the `var\log` folder?

Comment: thank you for your answer but let me be more specific, i did not get any blank page, i can see the header , the menu, the footer , background colour , generally i can see everything besides the product and its details.

Comment: @Vsld i've misread your question. But since the product displayed correctly when you changed the design, the problem still shouldn't be in your `view.phtml`

Comment: no problem my friend, but i do not know what to do in order to fix it.

Comment: @Vsld is logging enabled, and if so have you checked the log files?

Comment: i did not check the log files but i believe that logging is enabled.